# Replace badge images on Privileges

Tags: feature-request, badges, privileges, help-center

The badges found on [vote-up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) are just images.

> [image]

Can we have them instead use some html?

```
<span class="badge-container">
    <a href="/help/badges/6/supporter" title="bronze badge: First up vote" class="badge"><span class="badge3"></span>&nbsp;Supporter</a>
</span>
```

Moreover, there are no images, but just text found on the [set-bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). I believe that's inconsistent with the rest of the privileges layout.

> [image]

Having them as links that link to the proper badges page would be nice too.

There's also some pages that don't have any indication for badges, such as [vote-down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and [talk in chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat).

Comment: I think it's because originally those pages were written and maintained by ordinary users who can't inject the "real" badge view. Now that the pages are in the control of the team, I agree the badges should be "real". :)